# firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate not work with python shell

Tags: python, firebase, electron, firebase-admin

When I ran python3 main.py this is log: [image]

But when I used python sell in nodejs and I got this: [image]

What is wrong with firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate using python shell to call?
Here is my code to call [image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code as an image.